# Gradle project vs module dependency?

Tags: gradle, multi-module, build-dependencies

I'm familiar with `compile project(':A')` syntax where one submodule of a multi-module project declares a compile dependency on another submodule. Recently I came across  `compile module(':A')` (sorry, don't have the reference). How's the 2nd one different from the 1st?

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the docs:

23.4.2. Client module dependencies

Client module dependencies allow you to declare transitive dependencies directly in the build script. They are a replacement for a module descriptor in an external repository.

Example 23.8. Client module dependencies - transitive dependencies

```
build.gradle
dependencies {
    runtime module("org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.4") {
        dependency("commons-cli:commons-cli:1.0") {
            transitive = false
        }
        module(group: 'org.apache.ant', name: 'ant', version: '1.9.6') {
            dependencies "org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.9.6@jar",
                         "org.apache.ant:ant-junit:1.9.6"
        }
    }
}
```

See the documentation here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sub:client_module_dependencies

Comment: So it is to say that "Not only I know what dependencies I need, I also know what dependencies my dependencies need"? That's so ant-ish. Why'd anyone want to do that - it seems to be flies in the face of "dependency management"?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I am just showing you what the docs say and answering your question.